# Store derived classes in vector of type parent class and call derived classes methods

Tags: c++, class, pointers

First question here, so don't expect anything :)

I'll just start with an very abstract example of my code:

```
class Actor{
void move();
void attack();
}

class Player : public Actor{
void roll();
}

class Enemy : public Actor{
void explode();
}
```

Now it want to store all actors inside a vector (in practice I use a map for this):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>> actors;
```

Now, to add a Player-class to the array, I do:

```
actors.push_back(std::make_shared<Player>());
```

Now I want my Player to attack:

```
actors[0]->attack(); //works
```

Now I want my Player to roll:

```
actors[0]->roll(); //doesn't work
```

Only the methods of the actor class are shown when autocompleting (attack(), move()).

So I was wondering if there is a way to call Player/Enemy-class-specific methods.

Thanks guys, appreciate any helpers

Comment: Since they aren't `virtual` functions you need to downcast first (using `dynamic_cast` and a null pointer check to be safe)

Comment: However I'd rather question the design choice you have here. Why are you attempting to access functions that only exist within the derived class via pointers to the base class? This is often an error in your code design

Comment: Have you tried having actors hold a collection of pointers rather than the actual objects

Comment: Or you make the functions `virtual` and `Actor` picks up `roll` and `explode` that do nothing and are overridden by the derived classes with specialized behavior. This way no one ever needs to know what sort of `Actor` they're operating on.

Comment: @chickennuggies he is using smart pointers, that is completely fine